# Can you specify a "Where" in a SwiftUI ForEach statement?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In a SwiftUI application, I have a large class defining data. In part of the app, I would like to look at one record where the ID matches what I am looking for. I have done it as follows, but there seems it should be more straight forward. Such as allowing a where clause. Any ideas?

```
ForEach (ItemList) { item in 
    if (item.itemId = thisId) {
         Text(item.description)
    }
}
```

So rather than going thru the entire list to find the match, I'd like to:

```
ForEach (ItemList WHERE ID = XXX) {
```

OR (more preferably, since there is no "Each" and its only one record):

```
Text(ItemList[itemId].description)
```

Can't find any specific info on this, any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably something you should handle in your view model; Make the id a property of the view model and when that property is set you filter the data in your array and assign the filtered array to another property of your view model.  The `ForEach` then simply uses that array.

Comment: The other posted answer works as needed but would you mind posting a full answer detailing this suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this without the ForEach:

```
if let item = ItemList.first(where: {$0.id == "xxxx"}) {
   Text(item.description)
}
```