# How we can safely unwrap data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want safely unwrap data(with guard or any other way) for rendering my views in SwiftUI, here is my code:

I do not want use "??" and "Empty", I want safely unwrap my

> dataModel.items[index].name

, if there is something then show otherwise do nothing, as you can see in screenshoot we will got 4 views with this code, but it should be 2 views for "Data 1" and "Data 2"

PS: I am smart enough to know that I can use "" instead of "Empty", But "" is even a view, and I do not need it.

```
    struct Data: Identifiable
{
    let id  = UUID()
    var name: String?
}

let Data1 = Data(name: "Data 1")
let Data2 = Data(name: "Data 2")
let Data3 = Data()
let Data4 = Data()

class DataModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var items: [Data] = [Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4]
}



struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        ForEach(dataModel.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in

            Text(dataModel.items[index].name ?? "Empty")
                .font(.title2)
                .padding()
            
        }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

like my answer of: [Can you specify a "Where" in a SwiftUI ForEach statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637549/can-you-specify-a-where-in-a-swiftui-foreach-statement)

you could try something like this:

```
if let theName = dataModel.items[index].name {
    Text(theName).font(.title2).padding()
}
```